# how to instal MS SQL Server 2008 management studio in windows 8?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

I am using 64bit Windows 8 rtm.
Where can I get Sql server 2008 mgmt. studio for it?I tried installing sql server 2008 express sp1 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express SP1, but it wont install.(ref: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2012/03/02/sql-server-express-and-windows-8.aspx)
Can you provide me a link from where I can download a working setup and give step by step installation instructions?

Answer (score 2):

Well for a start the OS requires the appropriate version of MS SQL  to be installed. You may have difficulty in installing just the management studio because express is primarily designed to run on a stand alone machine. There is some configueration work to do to get ports open and protocols enabled. I suggest you install SQL 2008 R2 express with tools: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=26729

You want the *WT* (with tools versions)

however you may want to install sql 2012 express as this will connect to all earlier versions of MS SQL